# Round to nearest odd digit

Tags: math, lua

I want to round some numbers to the nearest tenth, using odd tenths only. e.g.

```
91.15 -> 91.1
91.21 -> 91.3
```

What's a simple and generic equation for doing this?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @lhf I have a generic script that takes data from a model and formats it for the screen. In this case, I'm mimicking FM radio stations, which (in the US) are 200kHz apart and always 'odd' as shown above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not rounding to the nearest tenth, but rather rounding to the nearest **fifth** (two-tenth) with a one-tenth offset. With that in mind, the general equation is:

```ruby
# Any language where 'round' rounds to the nearest integer
radioStation = round( (original-offset)/interval ) * interval + offset
```

In Lua:

```lua
-- number:   the original value to round
-- interval: the distance between desired values
-- offset:   an optional shifting of the values
function roundToNearest( number, interval, offset )
  offset   = offset   or 0  -- default value
  interval = interval or 1  -- default value
  return math.floor( (number-offset)/interval + 0.5 ) * interval + offset
end

for n=1, 2, 0.09 do
  local result = roundToNearest(n, 0.2, 0.1)
  print(string.format("%.2f : %g", n, result))
end
--> 1.00 : 1.1
--> 1.09 : 1.1
--> 1.18 : 1.1
--> 1.27 : 1.3
--> 1.36 : 1.3
--> 1.45 : 1.5
--> 1.54 : 1.5
--> 1.63 : 1.7
--> 1.72 : 1.7
--> 1.81 : 1.9
--> 1.90 : 1.9
--> 1.99 : 1.9
```

Comment: The idiomatic way is `offset = offset or 0`.

Comment: In the call to `roundToNearest`, it’s `n`, not `i`.

Comment: @lhf Bah, thank you. Silly refactoring in the edit box. And thanks for the Lua idiom; I get confused on the idiom for JS vs. Lua.

Comment: It is possible that `return math.floor( (number-offset) + (interval/2) ) + offset` might be a little faster.  On the order of nano-seconds per year. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
function roundToOdd(number)
    temp = math.floor(number * 10 + 0.5)
    if temp % 2 == 0 then
        -- first decimal is even, need to decide whether to "round" up or down 
        if number > temp/10 then
            -- closer to the next odd digit "up"
            temp = temp + 1
        else
            -- closer to the next odd digit "down"
            temp = temp - 1
        end
    end
    return temp/10
end

for n=1, 2, 0.09 do
  local result = roundToOdd(n, 0.2, 0.1)
  print(string.format("%.2f : %g", n, result))
end 
print(91.15,roundToOdd(91.15)) 
print(91.21,roundToOdd(91.21))
```

Results:

```
1.00 : 0.9
1.09 : 1.1
1.18 : 1.1
1.27 : 1.3
1.36 : 1.3
1.45 : 1.5
1.54 : 1.5
1.63 : 1.7
1.72 : 1.7
1.81 : 1.9
1.90 : 1.9
1.99 : 1.9
91.15   91.1
91.21   91.3
```

Comment: Since `temp = round(number * 10)` I don't see why in line 4: `number > temp` would ever be true.

Comment: @jessechisholm Thanks I must have modified after testing. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First let's answer the question how to find the nest odd integer, fast and efficient without branch and compare. Then that formula can be extended to the above question by first multiplying by a power of 10 before the transformation and then diving (converting back to float again) by the same power of 10, e.g. 10 for nearest odd tenth, 100 for the nearest odd hundredth, and so on.

If you are using languages like Java or C++ with truncated divide and bit-shift operator support, use this one line formula :

```java
// Java : with bit-shift
static int nearestOdd(float num) {
    return 1 + (((int)(num + 1.0f) - 1) & 0xFFFFFFFE);
}
    
// Java : without bit-shift.
static int nearestOdd(float num) {
    return 1 + 2 * (((int)(num + 1.0f) - 1) / 2);
}
```

In C++ :

```cpp
// C++
int nearestOdd(float num) {
  return 1 + ((static_cast<int>(num + 1.0f) - 1) & 0xFFFFFFFE);
}
```